# Solr full name search: how can I find entries containing a dash with wildcards

Tags: solr

I'm using solr 4.10.3. I tried to configure Solr to ignore dashes in searches:

```xml
<fieldtype name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <!-- sonderzeichen .,-\/ ignorieren -->
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[\.\-\\\/,]" replacement=""/>
    <!-- enthaelt u-umlaut -> u, lowercase und uft8 decomposed -->
    <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">

    <!-- sonderzeichen .,-\/ ignorieren -->
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[\.\-\\\/,]" replacement=""/>
    <!-- enthaelt u-umlaut -> u, lowercase und uft8 decomposed -->
    <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

I have an entry "pan-pan, peter", which is found, if i search

> *(peter pa*)*
>   *(peter panpa*)*

or even

> *(pe-te-r panpa*)*

also

> *(peter pa-n-pa-n)*

(without *) matches.

but

> *(peter pan-p*)*
>   *(peter pan\-p*)*

gives no result.

It seems as if the combination of dash and * is a problem?

I'd like to find `"pan-pan, peter"` in every stage of typing `"peter pan-pan"`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below field type.

```
<fieldType name="text_delimeter" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I tried with your text and analysed the same. I found the above type would work for you. I have analysed the same in the tool as well.

Comment: `<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>` solves my problem. thank you